# Group of order $11^2\times 13^2$

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to show that a group of order $11^2\times 13^2$ is abelian. I managed to show, by Sylow theorems, that if $G$ has order $11^2\times 13^2$, then $G = H.K$, with $|H|=11^2$, $|K|=13^2$ and $H,K$ normal subgroups of $G$ which are abelian (because their order is a square of a prime). But I don't think that the fact of $H$ and $K$ being abelian implies $G$ being abelian.

Comment: Prove that $H \cap K = 1,$  so that $G$ is the (internal) direct product $H \times K$ Convince yourself (and it is true) that the direct product of Abelian groups ia Abelian

Comment: Thank you, Geoff Robinson.